# Exclude/hide a field in Django form rendered with crispy-forms

Tags: python, django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I have two templates with the same form but on one page I do not want display 'photo' field. The problem  is that my form described via FormHelper of crispy-forms. How can I hide/exclude/delete 'photo' field and FormActions(Button)? Thanks in advance.

views.py:

```
    def user_data_view(request):
        model_values = UserData.objects.order_by('last_name')[0]
        form = User_data_form(initial={
            'name':model_values.name,
            'last_name':model_values.last_name,
            'birth_date':model_values.birth_date,
            'bio':model_values.bio,
            'email':model_values.email,
            'jabber':model_values.jabber,
            'skype':model_values.skype,
            })
       context = {
           'form':form,
       }
       return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class User_data_form(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = UserData
    fields = ['name', 'last_name', 'birth_date', 'bio', 'email', 'jabber','skype', 'photo']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(User_data_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.helper = FormHelper()

    self.helper.form_id = 'data-fields'
    self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
    self.helper.form_tag = True
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(
            Div('name', 'last_name', 'birth_date','email', 'jabber','skype','bio', css_class='col-md-6'),
            Div('photo', css_class='col-md-6'),
            HTML('<img src="{{ url_photo }}" id="photo-preview" class="pull-right form-inline">'),

        ),
        FormActions(
        Submit('save_changes', 'Save', css_class='btn btn-success'),

        )

    )
```

template.html

```
<form id="form" action="">{% csrf_token %}
{% crispy form %}
</form>
```

> Updated:

I rewrite forms.py code like so:

```
class FormMixin(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = UserData
    fields = ['name', 'last_name', 'birth_date', 'bio', 'email', 'jabber','skype', 'photo']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FormMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.helper = FormHelper()

    self.helper.form_id = 'data-fields'
    self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
    self.helper.form_tag = True
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(
            Div('name', 'last_name', 'birth_date','email', 'jabber','skype','bio', css_class='col-md-6'),
            Div('photo', css_class='col-md-6'),
            HTML('<img src="{{ url_photo }}" id="photo-preview" class="pull-right form-inline">'),
        ),
        FormActions()
        )

class User_data_form(FormMixin):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(User_data_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(),
        FormActions(
        Submit('save_changes', 'Save', css_class='btn btn-success'),
        )
    )

class InitialForm(FormMixin):
class Meta:
    model = UserData
    exclude = ['photo']
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(InitialForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

> But now I have Submit button on the top of form in second template. How to reassembly code to place button below  the form?

Comment: The easiest way would be to define a new form class. It can subclass the existing form class and would simply remove one field from `fields`.

Comment: Following you I made:
`class InitialForm(User_data_form):
    model = UserData
    exclude = ['photo']
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InitialForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`
but field still displaying...

Comment: It works for field (I missed class Meta in previous comment).But how exclude Button?

Comment: Same principle - only add the button in the layout that needs it. You should create a basic mixin class that both your forms subclass.

Answer (score 0):

not the best desicion, but nevertheless...

in template you want to hide the photo, just insert smth like that:

```
 <script> document.onLoad(function(){document.getElementById('form').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style = 'display:none';
}) </script>
```